# Unable to initialize device PRN

Tags: python-3.x

I am not able to run python from command prompt. It is showing unable to initialize device PRN when I type print("x").
I have checked, it is added in the PATH variable.

Comment: are u sure u are using python3? maybe u have 2 python libraries. try to start with "python3" and not "python" or check what it states when u use "python" if it is 2.7 or 3.*

Comment: I really think that the printer device should *not* be in the path...

Comment: How to check the path for printer device